# Prevent initial data load at history back

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

There is `Home.vue` and `Statistics.vue` pages. `Home.vue` render the `TableFields.vue` component. At `Home.vue` there is numbers with initial value "3" set on page load. Set interval function adds and calculate numbers every two seconds. How to achieve that those calculated numbers stay after going from home to statistics page and backwards, and reset only after page refresh? Router `index.js` file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import TableFields from '../components/TableFields.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: TableFields
  },
  {
    path: '/statistics',
    name: 'Statistics',
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (statistic.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "statistic" */ '../views/Statistics.vue')
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

App.vue file:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/statistics">Statistics</router-link>
    </div>
    <router-view :changesA.sync="changesA" :changesB.sync="changesB" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Project repo: [link](https://gitlab.com/srdjan-milic/factory-worldwide)

Comment: You'll want to use the [keep alive component](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `keep-alive` component to `router-view` component:

In yor App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/statistics">Statistics</router-link>
    </div>

    <keep-alive>
        <router-view :changesA.sync="changesA" :changesB.sync="changesB" />
    </keep-alive>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Wow! Is that simple. Thank you very much.